# Plot a matrix except for the first column

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I have a matrix that is 31x48. I would like to plot everything but the first column of the matrix as this data is not important.
for i = 1:22
plot(C1(i, :), 'color', 'b'), hold on
end

Not sure how I can exclude the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the first column simply by the following code:

```
plot(C1(i, 2:size(C1,2)), 'color', 'b')
```

Now you will start from the second column element to the last element.

Comment: **Tip**: you can replace the call to `size(C1,2)` by `end`, as in `C1(i, 2:end)` :)

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop. Use directly

```
plot(C1(1:22, 2:end).', 'b')
```

This works because [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) with a matrix input plots each column of the matrix (note the transposition in the above line)